# Parse complex string with one regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get from this string

```
genre:+Drama,Comedy+cast:+Leonardo+DiCaprio,Cmelo+Hotentot+year:+1986-1990
```

this

```
genre: [Drama, Comedy],
cast: [Leonardo DiCaprio, Cmelo Hotentot],
year: [1986-1990]
```

with one regular expression?

Comment: Why does it _have_ to be just one regex?

Comment: you can't, in general, because there are two levels of grouping for teh results (subject and entry), and regexps only support a single level.

Comment: I hoped for an elegant one regex :) I was just curious if it could be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using one regex and overload of `replace` function with replacer as a second argument. But honestly, I have to use one more `replace` to get rid of pluses (`+`) - I replaced them by a space () char:

```
var str = 'genre:+Drama,Comedy+cast:+Leonardo+DiCaprio,Cmelo+Hotentot+year:+1986-1990';
str = str.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
var result = str.replace(/(\w+:)(\s?)([\w,\s-]+?)(\s?)(?=\w+:|$)/g, function (m, m1, m2, m3, m4, o) {
    return m1 + ' [' + m3.split(',').join(', ') + ']' + (o + m.length != str.length ? ',' : '') + '\n';
});
```

You could find the full example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rHcVB/).

Answer (score 1):

You will not get them into arrays from the start, but it can be parsed if the order stays the same all the time.

```
var str = "genre:+Drama,Comedy+cast:+Leonardo+DiCaprio,Cmelo+Hotentot+year:+1986-1990";
str = str.replace(/\+/g," ");

//Get first groupings
var re = /genre:\s?(.+)\scast:\s?(.+)\syear:\s(.+)/
var parts = str.match(re)

//split to get them into an array
var genre = parts[1].split(",");
var cast = parts[2].split(",");
var years = parts[3];

console.log(genre);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the order will not stay the same all the time. Actually it will be always different

Comment: Than you need to do it in parts!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using only regular expressions cause you're trying to parse a (tiny) grammar.